# Using decorators in python to set global variables

Tags: python, sockets, scope, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I am attempting to reduce SLOC by using decorators.  I have a case that I need to start four TCP servers and save the connecting clients as global variables.  Here is the code.

```
# The sockets we will be using                                                             
socket0_client = None                                                                      
socket1_client = None                                                                      
socket2_client = None                                                                      
socket3_client = None                                                                      

# Populate them                                                                            
def save_client(global_client_var):                                                        
    def decorator(func):                                                                   
        async def inner(client, verbose=False):                                            
            global_client_var = client                                                     

            # Receive stuff                                                                
            with client:                                                                   
                while True:                                                                
                    # Get data.  If there is no data, quit                                 
                    data = await loop.sock_recv(client, 10000)                             
                    if not data:                                                           
                        break                                                              

                    # respond to the data                                                  
                    await func(client, data)                                               
        return inner                                                                       
    return decorator                                                                       

@save_client(socket0_client)                                                               
async def socket0_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(socket1_client)                                                               
async def socket1_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(socket2_client)                                                               
async def socket2_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(socket3_client)                                                               
async def socket3_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          

loop.create_task(tcp_server.single_server(('', 60001), task=socket0_reply, verbose=True))  
loop.create_task(tcp_server.single_server(('', 60002), task=socket1_reply, verbose=True))  
loop.create_task(tcp_server.single_server(('', 60003), task=socket2_reply, verbose=True))  
loop.create_task(tcp_server.single_server(('', 60004), task=socket3_reply, verbose=True))
```

There is a function that I don't have the code for.  It is the single_server function.  It binds to the server at the given address, waits for a connection, and then calls task on the newly connected client.

The problem that I have is that although client is populated in the inner function, and it is clearly set to global_client_var, the global sockets are never set.  They remain None.

What's going on here?  How can I get these global variables set?

Comment: why don't just declare `socket0_client` as global in function `socket0_reply` then set them to client instead ?

Comment: because that code will not be called until data is received from the socket.  I want to be able to use the socket elsewhere even before data has been received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the reference that a Python function argument points to, which is what your code is attempting to do.  All function call arguments in Python are passed by value; however, you *could* append an item to an incoming list or dictionary in this case:

```
sockets = {}                                                                     

# Populate them                                                                            
def save_client(global_client_var):                                                        
    def decorator(func):                                                                   
        async def inner(client, verbose=False):                                            
            sockets[global_client_var] = client                                                     

            # Receive stuff                                                                
            with client:                                                                   
                while True:                                                                
                    # Get data.  If there is no data, quit                                 
                    data = await loop.sock_recv(client, 10000)                             
                    if not data:                                                           
                        break                                                              

                    # respond to the data                                                  
                    await func(client, data)                                               
        return inner                                                                       
    return decorator                                                                       

@save_client(0)                                                               
async def socket0_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(1)                                                               
async def socket1_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(2)                                                               
async def socket2_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)                                          
@save_client(3)                                                               
async def socket3_reply(client, data):                                                     
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, b'Got:'+data)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in this case.  When I add the line 'global global_client_var' before I set it to client, it still has the value 'None' elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I misread the example code.  In function calls in Python all arguments are passed by value and cannot be used to update the reference the variable is bound to; however, you can pass something like a list or dictionary that could have a value appended to the collection.

Comment: This would work better if it were a dictionary.  The thing is that I need to know which socket belongs to what, and the append method will not allow me to keep track.

Comment: Agreed, using a dictionary and updating the decorator expression to specify keys versus variable references should do the trick.